# Removing an element from the array knowing its name

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array in PHP

```
array(5) {
  ["mai_id"] => string(1) "3"
  ["mai_logo"] => string(0) ""
  ["mai_title"] => string(16) "Vitrine Cultural"
  ["mai_description"] => NULL
  ["mai_description2"] => NULL
}
```

And I'd like to remove `["mai_description"]` and get only

```
array(5) {
  ["mai_id"] => string(1) "3"
  ["mai_logo"] => string(0) ""
  ["mai_title"] => string(16) "Vitrine Cultural"
  ["mai_description2"] => NULL
}
```

is there any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, use [unset()](https://www.php.net/unset)

```
unset( $array['mai_description'] );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
unset($array['mai_description'])
```

but use documentation, please.

Answer (score 2):

```
unset($array["mai_description"]);
```

ought to do the trick.

/ edited to fix syntax error even though it's the same as Peter's